# Is there options to set on Visual Studio to keep deterministic floating-point results between different multi-thread setup?

Tags: c++, floating-point, openmp, precision

I am working with OpenMp with VS2017 in order to compute our statistics with multi-thread process. But, for few values, we found out that results can be differents with the number of threads set. For these results, there isn't random or shared variables. The issues we encountered seems like this one: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/361052 (except, it's fortran). The solution given can't be good for my company because I am not alone to develop the software and I can't look for each code made by our statistician developer. So, I would like to know if there is an option to set on VS to get the same result whatever the number of thread set.

The solutions, I tried:

This is only for VS2017 or latest version. I tried to modify the floating point model with a strict (/fp:strict) value but this doesn't solve the issue. Then, I changed the enable enhanced instruction set with "Not Set" value, this has a real effect because 1, 2 and 3 threads have the same results but, with 4 threads, the results change. And it's the only options I know which can have effect on precision. Do you know other options ?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Full-Speed Deterministic Bit-Accurate Floating-Point Summation on Multi- and Many-Core Architectures](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Roman_Iakymchuk/publication/267982095_Full-Speed_Deterministic_Bit-Accurate_Parallel_Floating-Point_Summation_on_Multi-_and_Many-Core_Architectures/links/545ea4b10cf2c1a63bfc2093.pdf?inViewer=0&pdfJsDownload=0&origin=publication_detail).

Comment: Have you analyzed why you are getting varying results? Does the size of each job you are assigning to a thread vary with the number of threads? Do the threads produce results that are consolidated/combined in an order that depends on when the threads complete?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I will look for it. But first, I can say that the results are in a array/table in which each index is the number associated to the thread (using "#pragma omp parallel for" directive). So, the combination has no reason to change with the order of the threads.

Comment: Threading and non determinism is usually caused by threads overwriting each other's results (a.k.a. race condition) or improperly initialized variables.

Comment: Ok, I found a partial solution to my problem. The issues was mainly on the last number in my decimal. I decide to reduce the precision of this number which help me to keep the same results whatever the number of thread. Thanks for your ideas. They open my mind on new topics. I will read about it.